# Create table from simple UNION statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, union, union-all

What is wrong with this union? first 'select' and ')' are incorrect

```
create table GL_ALL
(
   select *from GL1
)
UNION
(
   select *from GL2
)
UNION
(
   select *from GL3
)
UNION
(
   select *from GL4
)
UNION
(
   select *from GL5
);
```

Comment: What's "right" with it would be easier... Basically nothing I'm afraid. You have a `CREATE TABLE` statement and then don't actually define what that table is. Then you have a bunch of subqueries, which aren't in a `FROM` and aren't aliased, and try to `UNION` them. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: What is it you want to do. Are you trying to copy the contents of `GL1` etc into a new table. If so it needs something like `SELECT * INTO newTable FROM oldTable`

Comment: hi, thank you. so all the 5 tables have the same format (same column names etc), I just want to merge them into one. what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Merge them into one to download/view, or actually make a new permanent table?

Comment: you just need to review the documentation for *union* - create your query that unions the tables successfully then add the *into targettable* on the first select only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for creating a table on the fly in SQL Server, or `UNION` for that matter.

Assuming that the schemas of each of your tables *are the same*

```
SELECT *
INTO GL_ALL FROM GL1 UNION
SELECT * FROM GL2 UNION
SELECT * FROM GL3 UNION
SELECT * FROM GL4 UNION
SELECT * FROM GL5;
```

As pointed out in comments, this will work for the initial creation of `GL_ALL`, but not for subsequent inserts after the table is created.

If you need to append to the table at a later time then the sytax changes to:

```
INSERT INTO GL_ALL
SELECT * FROM GL6;
```

It's important to realize that the new table will NOT have a primary key nor any foreign keys, indexes (clustered or non), constraints, defaults, etc. that the source tables may have.  If these are needed then you will need to manually create them.

And do note the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, where `UNION` will exclude duplicate rows.

Also note, it's best practice to avoid `SELECT *` and to specifically call out the columns you want to work with - even if it actually *is* all columns.

Comment: Worth noting on this a couple things on this - this will create the table and insert into it. For subsequent loads, you'll need to move the "INTO" line to the top of the query and make it "INSERT INTO". Additionally, I would encourage the asker to look into UNION vs. UNION ALL.

Comment: Yes, very valid points.